# iMac (late 2013) w/ High Sierra is very slow; lots of spinning wheels

Tags: imac, battery, permission

The last couple weeks, I've had infinite waits in many applications.  Logging in after restart took a few minutes, and the password space even disappeared for awhile.  Do these iMacs have batteries?  I don't remember.

I upgraded to Catalina a couple years ago but two apps I use all the time (Word for Mac, File Buddy) didn't work, so I went back to High Sierra.  I deleted the Google app today  taking up 3 gb and only compatible with Catalina or higher.

I have enough memory as far as I can tell via ActivityMonitor, except on one external HD that has 10gb left and 990gb used.  I did move 135 docs in my download folder to iCloud--everything seems a little better since then.

Does any of the info above mean impending doom for my iMac? I know relying on older systems can be problematic.

Thanks for any help on this.

Note:  One tag below about user permissions is included, because when I was looking for apps to delete, I had a document saved in the Applications folder, and I didn't have permission to move it.

Comment: You have a 10+ year old HDD in that iMac.  I would look at running disk drive diagnostic software like [Disk Drill](https://www.cleverfiles.com/) (Free for diags, $$ for recovery capability).

Comment: A quick internet [search](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iMac+Intel+21.5-Inch+EMC+2389+PRAM+Battery+Replacement/6292) shows my 2013 iMac has a battery. I run Catalina on an APFS formatted Samsung T7 USB SSD with much better speeds than using the internal APFS formatted HDD where High Sierra is installed. Your question does not specify the formatting (APFS/JHFS+), location (internal/external) or type (HDD/SSD/Fusion and SATA/PCIe/USB/Thunderbolt) where High Sierra is installed.

Comment: who is the heavies user of the resources in the Activity monitor ? or give us a screen shot

Comment: Thank you for your response; I like to know how things work.  Previously, I worked on my G5 and G4, 9500, the colorful G3 iMacs, and even earlier,  adding external hard drives with jumpers, designating slaves, etc.(I still have most of them).  That was then.

Answer (score 2):

If memory serves me correctly, you can upgrade the HDD to an SSD.
That will instantly give you better performance.

I did the same thing with an old white macbook of around the same year. and was good for a log while until i needed higher screen resolution. And is still performing OK now as its a spare Mac.

i believe they are standard 3.5" sata ssd drives, so you can pick one up quite cheaply.

1. back up everything
2. create a restore disk or usb
3. install clean OS on the SSD with external USB adapter
4. test the Mac booting so you know the SSD will work to boot
5. swap out old HDD for SSD
6. restore docs, files etc

good to go, with much improved performance. You might even consider leaving the HDD inside if you aren’t good with repairs.
Performance will be a bit slower and you might invest in a faster dock if you run external boot if needed.

Comment: For late 2013 iMacs, the size of the SATA drive depends on the screen size. Also, late 2013 iMacs support a PCIe blade SDD. See [here](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/imac-aluminum-tapered-edge-faq/how-to-upgrade-imac-hard-drive-aluminum-2012-2013.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

It might be your spotlight Indexing since you moved files

Try this to turn the indexing off temporary and see if that speeds up the computer

sudo mdutil -a -i off

This will turn off indexing of files, and should result in a clear slow down of the fans if mds and/or mds_stores are to blame.

To turn indexing back on, run

sudo mdutil -a -i on